# Creating a JavaScript Class which inherits from "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector"

Tags: inheritance, openlayers

I'm currently creating an application prototype which has an OpenLayers component in it (the map itself).

I want to create special "Features" wich will have additional properties.

They should inherit from *OpenLayers.Feature.Vector*, that is, use it's constructor with custom parameters and additional attributes.

I've been searching, but I can't find any simple example of how to do it.

*Note: My application object structure is not based on "OpenLayers.Class" typology, hence they are common javascript objects.

So here is the Class that should inherit from OpenLayers.Feature.Vector and should return a special instance of it,

```
// Class "SpecialRegion"
function SpecialRegion(bounds, options) {

 /* should return an OpenLayers.Feature.Vector with additional properties (objects) which makes this class different */

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend the OpenLayers.Feature.Vector class, which I strongly recommend, you will have to use the OpenLayers.Class object:

```
SpecialRegion = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector, {
    customAttribute: 'value',

    /**
     * OpenLayers Constructor
     */
    initialize: function(bounds, options) {
        // Call the super constructor, you will have to define the variables geometry, attributes and style
        OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.prototype.initialize.apply(this, {geometry, attributes, style});
        this.customAttribute = 'new value';
    },

    // Each instance will share this method. It's clean and efficient
    customMethod: function(param) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Instantiation

```
var myVector = new SpecialRegion(bounds, options);
myVector.customMethod(param);
var val = myVector.customAttribute;
```

If you only want to define special methods and/or attribute for a single instance, without having to define it's own class:

NOTE: Your application can become quite messy if you do this too often, I would suggest the solution above.

```
function customMethod2 = function(param) {
    ...
};

function SpecialRegion(bounds, options) {
    // Call the constructor, you will have to define the variables geometry, attributes and style
    var vector = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, attributes, style);

    vector.customAttribute = 'new value';

    // Each instance created with SpecialRegion will have their own copy of this method, the code is cleaner but it's memory inefficient
    vector.customMethod = function(param) {
        ...
    };

    // Each instance share the same copy of this method (defined on top), the code is harder to read/maintain but it's more memory efficient
    vector.customMethod2 = customMethod2;

    return vector;
};
```

Instantiation

```
var myVector = SpecialRegion(bounds, options);
// Don't use the keyword 'new' here, SpecialRegion is a function, not a proper class.
myVector.customMethod(param);
myVector.customMethod2(param);
var val = myVector.customAttribute;
```